# Configure Spring 4.1 O/X mapping to validate inbound XML based on a schema?

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, xsd, spring-oxm

Spring 4 O/X supports several XML unmarshallers behind its abstraction. We use JAXB2.

Can Spring validate the incoming XML against a schema? I didn't find anything in the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#oxm-jaxb2-xsd) nor in the spring-oxm [schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.1.xsd) that describe the configuration. This is my current configuration, pretty standard.

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <!-- properties here -->
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.Message1</value>
            <value>com.example.Message2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Can Spring validate the incoming XML against a schema?"

If you set the `schema` property:

```
public class Jaxb2Marshaller ... {
    /**
     * Set the schema resource to use for validation.
     */
    public void setSchema(Resource schemaResource) {
        this.schemaResources = new Resource[] {schemaResource};
    }

    /**
     * Set the schema resources to use for validation.
     */
    public void setSchemas(Resource... schemaResources) {
        this.schemaResources = schemaResources;
    }
}
```

the `Jaxb2Marshaller` will use those schema(s) to validate. So in your context xml, you can just do something like

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller"
    class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="schema" value="classpath:myschema.xsd"/> 
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.example.Message1</value>
            <value>com.example.Message2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```